# How can I implement a for loop in Haskell that iterates through all values of a list?

Tags: python, loops, haskell, for-loop

I am new to Haskell as well as functional programming. I have been searching for a way to iterate through all values in a list, but haven't found any.

Here is the Python code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
    matrix = [[2, 0, 1],[0, 1, 2],[1, 2, 0]]

    def is_associative(G):
        n = len(G)          
        return all(G[(G[x][y])][z] == G[x][(G[y][z])] for x in range(n) 
                   for y in range(n) for z in range(n))

    # is_associative(matrix) returns true

    def find_identity(G):
        n = len(G)
        for y in range(n):
            if all(G[x][y] == G[y][x] == x for x in range(n)):
                return y

    # find_identity(matrix) returns 1
```

Here is what I have so far in Haskell:

```
    isAssociative :: [[Int]] -> Bool
    isAssociative [[]] = False
    isAssociative test = do 
        let x = 0
        let y = 1
        let z = 2
        getValue test (getValue test x y) z == getValue test x (getValue test y z)

    getValue :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int
    getValue list a b = list !! a !! b

    findIdentity :: [[Int]] -> Int
    findIdentity test = 
        if all isTrue [ (g x y == g y x) && (g y x == x ) | x <- [0..n-1], y <- [0..n-1]]
            then 1 -- how to return y?
            else 0 -- how to return nothing?
        where n = length test
              g = getValue test
```

I have been able to fix my associativity function, but I still want to achieve the exact same functionality for finding the identity as the Python function.

**EDIT (PARTIALLY SOLVED -- need help with identity)**:

```
    isAssociative :: [[Int]] -> Bool
    isAssociative [[]] = False
    isAssociative test = 
        all id [ g (g x y) z == g x (g y z) | x <- [0..n-1], y <- [0..n-1], z <- [0..n-1]]
        where n = length test
              g = getValue test

    getValue :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int
    getValue list a b = list !! a !! b
```

Comment: You can write it almost identically using a list comprehension `isAssociative test = all [ g (g x y) z == g x (g y z) | x <- [1..n], y <- [1..n], z <- [1..n] ] where n = length test; g = getValue test`.

Comment: @user2407038 there was an error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘t0 a0 -> Bool’ Probable cause: ‘all’ is applied to too few arguments. Looking at documentation, `all` requires two parameters, but I don't think that would work here?

Comment: `isTrue` is just `id`

Comment: Python's list comprehension was inspired by Haskell's -- so it would be surprising if the Python solution couldn't be converted to Haskell fairly easily. Also -- becoming familiar with how Python 3 handles iterators, map, zip, etc., is a good a way to get used to the lazy approach to computation which is so central in Haskell.

Comment: @user2407038, @Kelly: that `all` shoud read `and`, which has the correct type `[Bool] -> Bool`.

Comment: @Cactus: good catch, thanks. Do you know how I am able to achieve the find_identity equivalent in Haskell? I tried `filter (\`elem\` y) [ y | (g x y == g y x) && (g y x == x ),  x <- [0..n-1], y <- [0..n-1]]` but it says y is not in scope.

Comment: @Kelly I'm not sure what the filter should do there - if you want to search for  (left) identity elements - `[ o | o <- [1..n], and [ g o x == x | x <- [1..n] ] ]`. This returns a list - there could be no identities, there could be one, and there could be many. You must discriminate between these cases if you want your return type to be `Int` (but you probably want `Maybe Int` - `Nothing` if there is no identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `findIdentity` part:

```
findIdentity :: [[Int]] -> Maybe Int
findIdentity ls = find 0 ls $ transpose ls where
  n = length ls - 1
  find _ [] [] = Nothing
  find y xs ys = if map head xs == map head ys && map head xs == [0..n]
                 then Just y
                 else if n == y
                      then Nothing
                      else find (y+1) (map tail xs) (map tail ys)


transpose :: [[b]] -> [[b]]
transpose [] = []
transpose ls | (length $ head ls) == 1 = [map head ls]
             | otherwise = map head ls:(transpose $ map tail ls)
```